# django - using of related_name in ManyToMany and in ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have two models (and also using the auth.user). the **auth.user** and the **Ride** model have two relations between them, and the **Ride** model and **Destination** model have two relations between them.

The Ride has **many** middle destinations and **one** final destination.
The Ride has **many** passengers and **one** driver.

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Ride(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='rides_as_driver')
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination)
    leaving_time=models.DateTimeField()
    num_of_spots=models.IntegerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name="rides_as_passenger")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToManyField(Destination)
```

I am trying to fully understand what is the meaning of the related_name attribute. I read a lot about it but still not sure...

Also I read that if I have two relations between to models, I have to use the related_name.

**Can someone explain to me:**

- What exactly is the related_name attribute? When do I use it?
- When and Where will I be using the rides_as_driver and rides_as_passenger?
- What should I put in the fields with the Destination? (middle destinations and final destination)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the name implies, this is the name you use when accessing the model from the related one. So, if you had a user instance, `my_user.rides_as_driver.all()` would give you all the Rides where `ride.driver == my_user`, and `my_user.rides_as_passenger.all()` would give you all the Rides where `ride.passengers` contains `my_user`.

Comment: thnaks! I thinkI got it

Answer (score 6):

Since you already have read about it on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), I will give a quick example.

You have a driver and you want to get a list of all related rides for the driver. Eg:

```
>>> driver = User.objects.first()
```

- Without specifying `related_name`:

  ```
  >>> driver.ride_set.all()
  ```
- With specifying a `related_name` as in your code:

  ```
  >>> driver.rides_as_driver.all()
  ```